# Select only updated/new rows in MySQL database/table

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, myisam

In my current project I'm trying to check a MySQL database: a MySQL database is updated by another program, so my C++ program needs to select only the new rows. It is not going to be a small table (>10000 rows), so I do not want to search each row. i.e. checking a column like isNew=0 or =1.  I already found:

[Query to find tables modified in the last hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492040/query-to-find-tables-modified-in-the-last-hour)

http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/how-to-check-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated/

However, in this example you can only get the table which is updated. How can I only select the new rows from a table?

Comment: If you need to do this a lot, why not have a `is_new` or `inserted_datetime` column, and make an index on that column?

Comment: I don't think you can in your example. You could possibly do a hack to have your program check the replication logs or something and get your information from there. But 10000 rows really isn't a very big table for MySQL.

Comment: What's wrong with an additional `isNew` column or better yet a timestamp column? Searching 10,000 rows is a piece of cake for mysql.

Comment: So, until how many rows is that an option for mysql?

Comment: @Rogier "until how many"... is a question that only **you** can answer. When it gets too slow for you, then it's no longer an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding an `isNew` column to the table with default value 1 and add an index on it. The index will prevent your query from checking all rows. After you have processed the row, set `isNew` to 0.

Comment: Is this possible in one query?

Comment: You would need multiple queries. `select * from table where isNew = 1` to get new entries and then `update table set isNew = 0` when done.

Comment: That's a pity ;) I was wondering if there is something like "select update" similar to "select into"

Answer (score 4):

> How can I only select the new rows from a table?

Assuming new rows means newly inserted, and if you can change the database schema, you could use an [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) column. By remembering the largest value each time your program selects a result set, it could save that value for the next query:

```
select * from table where id > 123
```