# Check affected tables via application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I am working in an application which is already developed by some one.
There is lot of tables get participated/affected for a single operation.

I cannot go through all DAO classes and check whether table is used for that particular flow or not...

Is there any way to find the affected tables for a request/response.

Am using Java-Spring framework, JDBC template.

Your answers will save my huge time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/678310/1816093) on The Stack

Comment: If you have the permission to access mysql, check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492040/query-to-find-tables-modified-in-the-last-hour). I believe if you modify the query slightly you can get your result.